# Hazelcast: Could not join cluster. Shutting down now

Tags: docker, hazelcast

We are trying to create a Hazelcast cluster with two Docker containers and access it from the client application, but we are able to start one HazelCast container and while starting another getting Could not join cluster. Shutting down now. exception.

We have used below commands to start docker containers.

```
 $ docker run -e JAVA_OPTS="-Dhazelcast.local.publicAddress=<host_ip>:5701" -p 5701:5701 hazelcast/hazelcast
 $ docker run -e JAVA_OPTS="-Dhazelcast.local.publicAddress=<host_ip>:5702" -p 5702:5701 hazelcast/hazelcast

docker run -d --rm -e JAVA_OPTS="-Dhazelcast.local.publicAddress=127.0.0.1:5701" -p 5701:5701 hazelcast/hazelcast
docker run -d --rm -e JAVA_OPTS="-Dhazelcast.local.publicAddress=127.0.0.1:5702" -p 5702:5701 hazelcast/hazelcast
```

Comment: I ran a test and I don't see issues... I think you chose a host_ip that can't be properly reached.

Comment: I have updated question with host_ip

Comment: One instance works fine but problem occurs when we try to start second instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the IP you're using. The loopback IP should be avoided when creating a cluster of machines (unless they're physically on the machine itself but this is not the case). Try to get your pc ip address and use that.